# How do I use custom fields in hyperlinks?

Tags: expressionengine

Would anyone know how to link the custom field to a page that lies 4 segments deep?

```
<td valign="top" align="center">Hotels:</td>
<td valign="top">{toursRelatedHotels}{title}{/toursRelatedHotels}</td>
```

I would like to link the `{title}` of the Hotels field, Im finding it hard to do so.

The way I am doing it is as follows

```
{toursRelatedHotels}<a href="{title_permalink='destination/{toursRelatedCountries}{url_title}{/toursRelatedCountries}'}">{title}</a>{/toursRelatedHotels}
```

It seems that the url_title cannot be seen of the country in the link. how else can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I usually build sites with the (commercial) add-on Structure, which allows you to easily use a {page_url} tag pretty much anywhere and avoid numerous url depth issues.

http://buildwithstructure.com/

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us a bit more info, or maybe include the full template code? Are you trying to access the url_title of the related entry, or the parent entry?

ExpressionEngine can be a bit funny when you are trying to show information about related entries. Often the best thing to do is to embed a new template inside your related entries loop.

{toursRelatedHotels}

{embed="template_group_name/template_name" hotel_id="{entry_id}"}

{/toursRelatedHotels}

Have a look here for more info - http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html